# Can we assume computer be fast enough?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Consider such a question

> Take a program `P` and an integer `n`, check whether `P` halts. You may assume that if `P` halts then `P` halts in `n` steps.

and solution 1

```
(P,n)=>!run(P,timeout=n us).timeout
```

solution 2

```
P=>!run(P,timeout=9 us).timeout
```

where S1 assumes `n` steps will finish in `n` us and S2 assume in 9 us.

Do we allow such assumption in code-golf?